# How to get the error/reason behind "make test -- NOT OK" in Perl CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm on Windows 10, MSYS2 console; and I try to do this:

```
$ cpan CPAN::DistnameInfo
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '~/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 11 May 2021 20:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'CPAN::DistnameInfo'
Checksum for ~/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GB/GBARR/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12.tar.gz ok
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring G/GB/GBARR/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for CPAN::DistnameInfo
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  GBARR/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for G/GB/GBARR/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12.tar.gz
cp lib/CPAN/DistnameInfo.pm blib/lib/CPAN/DistnameInfo.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  GBARR/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12.tar.gz
  make -- OK
Running make test for GBARR/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12.tar.gz
  GBARR/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12.tar.gz
  make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports GBARR/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12.tar.gz
```

Well, it's nice knowing that `make test` is `NOT OK` - but what *is* the actual problem?

Strangely, if I do manually:

```
$ cd ~/.cpan/build/CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12-4/
$ make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/ext.t ... ok
t/path.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=2, Tests=829,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr  0.05 sys +  0.42 cusr  0.28 csys =  0.82 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

... then, `make test` seems to work ?!

So - how can I find the actual error reason?

Comment: It works fine for me (MSYS2, Windows 10). [Here](https://pastebin.com/BtVfJSXX) is the output I get.

Comment: Do either of the test files or Makefile.PL do anything weird with different behaviour based on different environment variables? `cpan` might be setting an environment variable which isn't set when you're running the tests manually.

Comment: From within `cpan`, can you do `o conf build_dir_reuse 0` followed by `o commit`, and try again?

Comment: If that test passes, I'd continue with `make install` then get on with life. :)

Comment: True that. . . .

Comment: @HåkonHægland did you do anything different? i am also 1on MSYS2, win 10; but failing like the questino

Comment: @sdauu how did you get cpan there? for me, even `bash: cpan: command not found`! so, i had to do via `perl -MCPAN -e shell` as shared here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-install-a-perl-module/

Comment: for anyone trying, none of these helped either: `cpan> upgrade` , or switching from `msys` perl to `mingw-w64` perl (total 4 combinations)